# kafka-python: producer is not able to connect

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

kafka-python (1.0.0) throws error while connecting to the broker.
At the same time /usr/bin/kafka-console-producer and /usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer work fine.

Python application used to work well also, but after zookeeper restart, it no longer can connect.

I am using bare bones example from the docs:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.common import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['hostname:9092'])

# Asynchronous by default
future = producer.send('test-topic', b'raw_bytes')
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pp.py", line 4, in <module>
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['hostname:9092'])   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 246, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = client.check_version()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 629, in check_version
    connect(node_id)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 592, in connect
    raise Errors.NodeNotReadyError(node_id) kafka.common.NodeNotReadyError: 0 Exception AttributeError: "'KafkaProducer' object has no attribute '_closed'" in <bound method KafkaProducer.__del__ of <kafka.producer.kafka.KafkaProducer object at 0x7f6171294c50>> ignored
```

When stepping through ( /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py) I noticed that line 270 evaluates as false:

```
270         if not self._metadata_refresh_in_progress and not self.cluster.ttl() == 0:
271             if self._can_send_request(node_id):
272                 return True
273         return False
```

In my case  self._metadata_refresh_in_progress is False, but the ttl() = 0;

At the same time kafka-console-* are happily pushing messages around:

```
/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list hostname:9092 --topic test-topic
hello again
hello2
```

Any advice?

Comment: To void complexity, Kafka does not require a zookeeper anymore. Another thing depending on your OS, an ifconfig command can give you a host IP address that you should use.

Answer (score 35):

I had the same problem, and none of the solutions above worked. Then I read the exception messages and it seems it's mandatory to specify api_version, so

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],api_version=(0,1,0))
```

> note: tuple `(1,0,0)` matching to kafka version `1.0.0`

works fine (at least completes without exceptions, now have to convince it to accept messages ;) )

Comment: but then it stops after sending the first message

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Kafka 0.10 broke kafka-python for me otherwise.

Comment: If anyone is having trouble where it's not sending any more data after the first message, you have to do `producer.flush()` in order to clear out the send buffers.

Comment: `api_version` is not mandatory in version 1.3.5. However, not using the keyed argument will make it attempt to automatically detect the version, which is failing on my current broker (docker image wurstmeister/kafka-docker)

Comment: Wow i did days of debugging and this finally helped! For context, Heroku was not able to send the message until I specified the version explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. In my case, broker hostname was unresolvable on the client side . Try to explicitly set `advertised.host.name` in the configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

A  host could have multiple dns aliases. Any of them would work for ssh or ping test. However kafka connection should use the alias that matches `advertised.host.name` in `server.properties` file of the broker.

I was using a different alias in `bootstrap_servers` parameter. Hence an error. Once I changed the call to use `advertised.hostname`, the problem was solved

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I solved the problem with hint of user3503929.

The kafka server was installed on windows.

server.properties

```
...
host.name = 0.0.0.0
...
```

.

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='192.168.1.3:9092',         
                                         value_serializer=str.encode)
producer.send('test', value='aaa')
producer.close()
print("DONE.")
```

There was no problem with the processing in the windows **kafka** client.
However, when I send a message to topic using **kafka-python** in **ubuntu**, a `NoBrokersAvailable` exception is raised.

Add the following settings to server.properties.

```
...
advertised.host.name = 192.168.1.3
...
```

It runs successfully in the same code.
I spent three hours because of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install kafka-python using `pip install kafka-python`

**Steps to create kafka data pipeline:-**
1. Run the Zookeeper using shell command or install zookeeperd using

```
sudo apt-get install zookeeperd
```

This will run zookeeper as a daemon and by default listens to 2181 port

2. Run the kafka Server
3. Run the script with producer.py and consumer.py on separate consoles to see the live data.

Here are the commands to run:-

```
cd kafka-directory
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  ./config/zookeeper.properties    
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh  ./config/server.properties
```

Now that you have zookeeper and kafka server running, Run the producer.py script and consumer.py

Producer.py:

from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
topic = 'test'
lines = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
for line in lines:
  try:
    producer.send(topic, bytes(line, "UTF-8")).get(timeout=10)
  except IndexError as e:
    print(e)
  continue
```

Consumer.py:-

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
topic = 'test'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
for message in consumer:
    # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
    # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
    # print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
    #                                       message.offset, message.key,
    #                                       message.value))
    print(message)
```

Now run the producer.py and consumer.py in separate terminals to see the live data..!

**Note**: Above producer.py script runs once only to run it forever, use while loop and use time module.

Comment: Works perfectly on the new Mac M1, version of `kafka-python` 2.0.2. Mainly due to the `.get(timeout=10)`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and removing the port from the bootstrap_servers helped.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my_topic',
                     #group_id='x',
                     bootstrap_servers='kafka.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your server.properties file make sure he Listener IP is set to your box Ip address which is accessible to remote machine. By default it is localhost

Update this line in your server.properties:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<Your-IP-address>:9092
```

Also make sure you don't  have a firewall which might be blocking other IP addresses to reach you. If you have sudo previleges. The try disabling the firewall.

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```