# Connecting Kafka-Python with a cluster with Kerberos

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to connect to a Kafka with Kafka-Python, the Kafka cluster has Kerberos that we need to build some commands to do few steps.

I have created one Topic at the cluster and I did the test with `./kafka-console-producer.sh` and `./kafka-console-consumer.sh` and works really well.

But when I try to connect with Kafka-Python I had a problem. See my code below:

```
def produce():
    print ('Producer')
    k_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='hostname:6667', 
                               security_protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT',
                               sasl_plain_username='machine_usr',
                               sasl_plain_password='machine_pwd',
                               sasl_mechanism='PLAIN')
    for i in range(10):
        print ('Before send')
        k_producer.send('myTopic', 'Testing My Topic  ' + str(i))
        print ('After send')
```

Well, running this stuff I got this erro message after 30 secconds:

```
File "C:\Users\m\kafka-python-1.3.1\kafka.zip\kafka\producer\kafka.py", line 328, in __init__
File "C:\Users\m\kafka-python-1.3.1\kafka.zip\kafka\client_async.py", line 202, in __init__
File "C:\Users\m\kafka-python-1.3.1\kafka.zip\kafka\client_async.py", line 791, in check_version
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

I'm running it in a remote machine. And the bootstrap_server I used the Zookeeper hostname and port but didn't work as well.

I found few things about it, and in the git of the Kafka-Python I found that they had [implemented](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/533).

Is there other way to connect?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the contents of your working scripts.  Also did you see this OP using a much simpler connection?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689238/kafka-python-producer-is-not-able-to-connect  It might be a place to start, even if you have to set up a separate instance without Kerberos.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWisehart! I know that we could be able to connect in a simple way. But the Kerberos make the things a little bit harder... I need to make an authentication with KeyTab... And it is not able to do that in python lib.

Comment: is the address of your kafka broker `hostname:6667` ? that doesn't seem right at first glance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well Guys,

I found the issue.

The problem is that Kerberos is not supported for Kafka producer in Python using Key Tab.

To use Key Tab we need to set a java Environment Variable.

According [Hortonworks](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_secure-kafka-ambari/content/ch_secure-kafka-produce-events.html) we need to set the client_jaas_client to connect.

The solution was using Py4j to call the Kafka Producer in JVM.

See the example [here](https://gist.github.com/TRBaldim/2bf67f21bd31ceca3c44f12208a86be6).

Comment: Do you have an implementation example of this? Stuck in a similar situation. How do you use Py4j to call the Kafka Producer in JVM?

Comment: Hey, this is the example I have used almost 4 years ago. That worked, unfortunately I don't have the original code :( 

https://gist.github.com/TRBaldim/2bf67f21bd31ceca3c44f12208a86be6

Answer (score 5):

If the task is to solve this problem in python, another alternative could be to use [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) library that internally uses [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) that is written in C, and supports SASL, and the use of the keytab file. That wouldn't require having a separate Java process for the communication with kafka over SASL.

For instructions also refer to the documentation of the [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) library:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka - general intro
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md - the properties that can be passed into the constructor of `confluent_kafka.Producer` and `confluent_kafka.Consumer` in python